# how to output any std::basic_string to console?

Tags: c++, string, output

I have to make a function that prints `std::basic_string` to console but I have no idea how to do it

Signature of function should be like

```
template<typename CharT, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, typename Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>>
void print(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>&);
```

I have tried to create std::basic_ostream object but it requires std::streambuf which doesn't have public constructor.
Also I guess that I can do something like

```
template<typename CharT, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, typename Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>>
void print(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& text) {
    for (auto el : text)
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(el);
}
```

but I ain't sure if this is a good idea(std::basic_string and values bigger than 256)

Comment: This is not that straignt forward. This will depend on the console. If the console is configured to accept `UTF-8` input, then your program needs to take any `std::basic_string` and convert it's contents to `UTF-8`. That, in turn will depend on the encoding that the `std::basic_string` contains. This will often be (but not exclusively) either `UTF-16`or `UTF-32` or `UTC`.

Comment: `basic_string` isn't a complete type, it's a template.  Until you know what the template type is you won't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is to just get rid of the template parameters and overload your function on `std::string` and `std::wstring`, then you can write them to `std::cin` and `std::wcout`, respectively.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to print any specialization of `std::basic_string` in the first place? Would it not be sufficient to only cover the UTF ones and `std::string`? What is the design goal?